Volcano Exploration / Sci-Fi - Fantastic
I was very young when I saw this movie but I'd say it should have been made during the 80s, likely produced in the US and I wouldn't be surprised if it was a just a tv movie. I was too young to recognise any actor. It didn't seem extremely good but I was very impressed by the visual aspect back then (I was about 4 or 5).
The main story is about volcano exploration (or at least underground, but I remember seeing a lot of lava in this movie). Scientists find a way to build a machine able to carry people inside a volcano, probably in order to study it. 
A first team of explorers is sent, including a friend or a brother/brother-in-law of the main character (both males). Before the operation begins, the friend, sitting in the machine, gives his wedding ring to the hero for some reason (I'm not 100% sure if he's giving or being given). 
The operation starts, and they lose contact with the exploration team after a while. The hero decides to lead his own exploration team in order to find his friend. However, they find out that some kind of "another race" is living down there. They have a human form, but quite creepy with some marks on their face. They're hostile, and they have a leader who's basically the main antagonist.
I don't remember much about the middle of the movie. In the end though, the hero find their machine that was stolen by the bad guys. They need it to go back to the surface. They struggle with the leader while the machine is going up, until the antagonist falls to its death right into the lava. 
As I told earlier, I remember seeing a lot of lava, giving the movie a quasi constant red shade. 
That's all I can remember guys. I made all of the research possible, googled every detail to no avail.

If it wasn't for the lava people, I'd say this was The Core

This sounds like the old Doug McClure film At The Earth's Core, which was based on a book by Edgar Rice Burroughs.
There were certainly a lot of reddish backgrounds in that film.  Our heroes enter the earth by tunnelling into the side of a volcano.
If memory serves, the business with the wedding ring and the fight at the end were both in it too.
It dates from 1976 so close to your recollection of the '80s.

It's called "Journey To The Center Of The Earth". It was a 1993 TV movie. I have spent years trying to find this. I saw you question and decided to look again. Here is the full movie on YouTube. 




while this MIGHT be the answer, adding detail to this answer as to WHY it would be the correct answer, and how you came to this conclusion, would make it a higher quality answer
